# How do I show that $0<a_n^2<a_n$ If $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Since $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, i know know that $\lim _{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.

I know I have to use the comparison test to show that ${a_n}^2$ converges but how do i show that $0<a_n^2<a_n$ so i can apply the comparison test? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Eventually, $a_n<1$ and then $a_n^2<a_n$.

Comment: @alex Apart from the OP's name, how did you choose the answer you accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $a_n$ must converge to 0, i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=0$. This means that $a_n<1$ for all $n\geq N$ for some $N$. It follows that $0\leq a_n^2<a_n$ for $n\geq N$ and now the comparison test works.

Comment: perfect thank you very much!!

Comment: What exactly makes that "$a_n$ must decrease to $0$ at some point"? This seems obviously not guaranteed.

Comment: @Did: the way OP wrote it, I thought it was implied that $a_n>0$ is an assumption.

Comment: Yes, $a_n>0$ for every $n$, and why would this imply that $(a_n)$ decreases to $0$?

Answer (score 3):

**Methodology Ideas**

1. As written, it's not true. Nothing requires $a_n > 0$ at all. For the rest, let's assume you omitted the assumption that $a_n$ is positive.
2. It might not be true that $a_n^2 < a_n$ for all $n$.
3. What *exactly* does it mean to say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$?
4. Recall that if $|x| < 1$, then $|x|^2 < |x|$.